# VuexFire: how to combine computed: and computed()

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex

I am using VuexFire in an app and as in https://github.com/posva/vuexfire in my components I have lines like

```
   computed: Vuex.mapGetters(['todos']),
   created() {
     this.$store.dispatch('setTodosRef', todosRef)
   },
```

This works fine except when I also have some computed methods in which case I don't know what to do. I have tried things like:

```
   computed: Vuex.mapGetters(['todos']),
   computed() {
      amethod: { return 1 }
   },
   created() {
     this.$store.dispatch('setTodosRef', todosRef)
   },
```

and

```
   computed() {
      amethod: { return 1 }
   },
   created() {
     ...Vuex.mapGetters(['todos'])
     this.$store.dispatch('setTodosRef', todosRef)
   },
```

but these, and the other things that I have tried, are clearly misguided because they don't work (i.e. the data from firebase is not available to the method.

What's the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you will always specify your computed properties as an object, not as a method (as you're doing with `computed()`).

Secondly, you need to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in the `computed` object:

```
computed: {
  amethod() { return 1 },
  ...Vuex.mapGetters(['todos'])
}
```

This effectively spreads out all of the computed property methods returned by `Vuex.mapGetters` and defines them as properties of the `computed` object.

Comment: Thanks very much. Not sure why I didn't try this!